# JOIN on ID, IF ID doesn't match then match on other columns BigQuery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, case

I have two tables that I am trying to join. The tables have a primary and foreign key but there are some instances where the keys don't match and I need to join on the next best match.

I tried to use a case statement and it works but because the join isn't perfect. It will either grab the incorrect value or duplicate the record.

The way the table works is if the `Info_ID`s don't match up we can use a combination of `Lev1` and if the `cust_start` date is between `Info_Start` and `Info_End`

I need a way to match on the IDs and then the SQL stops matching on that row. But im not sure if that is something BigQuery can do.

Customer Table

```
Cust_ID Cust_InfoID Cust_name   Cust_Start  Cust_Lev1
1111    1           Amy         2021-01-01  A
1112    3           John        2020-01-01  D
1113    8           Bill        2020-01-01  D
```

Info Table

```
Info_ID Info_Lev1   Info_Start  Info_End    state
1       A           2021-01-15  2021-01-14  NJ
3       D           2020-01-01  2020-12-31  NY
5       A           2021-01-01  2022-01-31  CA
```

Expected Result

```
Cust_ID Cust_InfoID Info_ID Cust_Lev1   Cust_Start  Info_Start  Info_End    state
1111    1           1       A           2021-01-01  2021-01-15  2021-01-14  NJ
1112    3           3       D           2020-01-01  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  NY
1112    8           3       D           2020-01-01  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  NY
```

Join Idea 1:

```
CASE
  WHEN
    (Cust_InfoID = Info_ID) = true
    AND (Cust_Start BETWEEN Info_Start AND Info_End) = true
  THEN
    Cust_InfoID = Info_ID
  ELSE
    Cust_Start BETWEEN Info_Start AND Info_End
    and Info_Lev1 = Cust_Lev1
END

Output:
Cust_ID Cust_InfoID Info_ID Cust_Lev1   Cust_Start  Info_Start  Info_End    state
1111    1           5       A           2021-01-01  2021-01-01  2022-01-31  CA
1112    3           3       D           2020-01-01  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  NY
1113    8           3       D           2020-01-01  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  NY
```

The problem here is that IDs match but the dates don't so it uses the ELSE statement to join. This is incorrect

Join Idea 2:

```
CASE
  WHEN
    Cust_InfoID = Info_ID
  THEN
    Cust_InfoID = Info_ID
  ELSE
    Cust_Start BETWEEN Info_Start AND Info_End
    and Info_Lev1 = Cust_Lev1
END

Output:
Cust_ID Cust_InfoID Info_ID Cust_Lev1   Cust_Start  Info_Start  Info_End    state
1111    1           1       A           2021-01-01  2021-01-15  2021-01-14  NJ
1111    1           5       A           2021-01-01  2021-01-01  2022-01-31  CA
1112    3           3       D           2020-01-01  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  NY
1113    8           3       D           2020-01-01  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  NY
```

The problem here is that IDs match but the ELSE statement also matches up the wrong duplicate row. This is also incorrect

Example tables here:

```
with customer as (
    SELECT 1111 Cust_ID,1 Cust_InfoID,'Amy' Cust_name,'2021-01-01' Cust_Start,'A' Cust_Lev1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1112,3,'John','2020-01-01','D'
    union all 
    SELECT 1113,8,'Bill','2020-01-01','D'
),
info as (
    select 1 Info_ID,'A' Info_Lev1,'2021-01-15' Info_Start,'2021-01-14' Info_End,'NJ' state
    union all 
    select 3,'D','2020-01-01','2020-12-31','NY'
    union all 
    select 5,'A','2021-01-01','2022-01-31','CA'
)
select Cust_ID,Cust_InfoID,Info_ID,Cust_Lev1,Cust_Start,Info_Start,Info_End,state
from customer 
join info on 
[case statement here]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The way the table works is if the Info_IDs don't match up we can use a combination of Lev1 and if the cust_start date is between Info_Start and Info_End

Use two `left join`s, one for each of the conditions:

```
select c.*,
       coalesce(ii.info_start, il.info_start),
       coalesce(ii.info_end, il.info_end),
       coalesce(ii.state, il.state)
from customer c left join
     info ii
     on c.cust_infoid = ii.info_id left join
     info il
     on ii.info_id is null and
        c.cust_lev1 = il.info_lev1 and
        c.cust_start between il.info_start and il.info_end
```

Comment: This works! Just out of curiosity, is it even possible to do it with one JOIN and a CASE statement?

Comment: @JoeDemochettie . . . Not really.  There are games you can play with window functions but this probably has the best performance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below ("with one JOIN and a CASE statement" as asked)

```
select any_value(c).*, 
  array_agg(i order by 
    case when c.cust_infoid = i.info_id then 1 else 2 end
    limit 1
  )[offset(0)].*
from `project.dataset.customer` c 
join `project.dataset.info` i
on c.cust_infoid = i.info_id 
or(
  c.cust_lev1 = i.info_lev1 and
  c.cust_start between i.info_start and i.info_end
)
group by format('%t', c)
```

when applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: have you tried? I would expected it to be more effective than two joins :o)